# Python Module Session error in raspberry pi

Tags: session, module

Good day! everyone I just want to share my problems regarding my raspberry pi work, thank you for the ones that can provide me some tips and ideas on how to fix my problem.

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Session'

this is my error code.. here's the pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR9EW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code of your ysoy.py data.
When you use GPIO from RPI on your raspberry you always have to set up `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)` or `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` befor using the PINs.